# Handler pause or stop action

Tags: android, button, handler, runnable

I have 5 `Buttons`. Each `Button`'s text is set to one random letter from `list_of_letters`. Also, the letters are displayed one at a time, every 5 seconds - which is why I use a `Handler` and `Runnable`. And every 5 seconds, that letter that was added to the `Button` gets removed from `list_of_letters`.

Problem: When all 5 `Buttons` contain a letter, the `Runnable` is still running and removing letters from `list_of_letters` every 5 seconds. Is there a way I can pause the `Handler` or stop its action so it will only run when a `Button` does not contain text?

Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable x = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    random_counter = rand.nextInt(my_list_counter); 
                    for(Button b:button_list) //contains the 5 buttons
                        if (b.getText().equals("")){ //if button is empty, add text to it
                            b.setText(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //sets text to random letter from List
                            break;
                        }
                    list_of_letters.remove(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //then removes that letter from the List
                    my_list_counter--;
                }
            };
           Handler handler = new Handler();
           handler.postAtTime(x, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + i*5000); //a letter gets posted every 5 seconds
        }
```

EDIT: Here is my current code. There is an error at `handler.post(x)`. The error says: local variable `x` may not have been initialized.

```
 final Runnable x = new Runnable() {
             @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(my_list_counter <= 0) 
                        return;     // i'm guessing my_list_counter is the length of the array/list.
                    random_counter = rand.nextInt(my_list_counter);          

                    for(Button b:button_list) //contains the 5 buttons 
                    {
                         if (b.getText().equals("")) { //if button is empty, add text to it
                             b.setText(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //sets text to random letter from List
                             list_of_letters.remove(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //then removes that letter from the List
                             my_list_counter--;

                             Handler handler = new Handler();
                             handler.post(x);
                            // handler.postAtTime(x, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 5000); //a letter gets posted every 5 seconds

                             break;
                          }
                     }
                }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move part of your code that remove the letters and creates a new handler to be inside the loop :

```
@Override
public void run(){
    if(my_list_counter <= 0) return;     // i'm guessing my_list_counter is the length of the array/list.
    random_counter = rand.nextInt(my_list_counter);          

    for(Button b:button_list) //contains the 5 buttons 
    {
         if (b.getText().equals("")) { //if button is empty, add text to it
             b.setText(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //sets text to random letter from List
             list_of_letters.remove(list_of_letters.get(random_counter)); //then removes that letter from the List
             my_list_counter--;

             Handler handler = new Handler();
             handler.postDelayed(x, 5000); //a letter gets posted every 5 seconds

             break;
          }
     }
}
```

**Edit  :** you can use postDelayed instead of postAtTime. the interval wont be exactly 5 seconds, but is very near (milliseconds difference).

move the `Runnable X = new Runnable()` initialization to outside any method.

for example, if your code is inside an activity :

```
public class yourClass extends Activity
{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //....
     }

     Runnable x = new Runnable()
     {
         // the rest of the code.
     };
}
```

and call `new Handler().post(x);` to get it started.

Comment: I will try this but there are some bugs here: the 'i' is not defined in handler.postAtTime and x doesn't exist either

Comment: When I add final Runnable x = new Runnable to your answer I still get an error at line: handler.postAtTime(x, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + i*5000);   It says the local variable x mat not have been initialized. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Happy Cupz Cupz but there is still an error. I edited my post above with the problem. Please let me know if you can help. thanks again

Comment: still not working unfortunately. It will only let me create the Handler outside the for loop, which is what I had before...

Comment: are you still getting the local variable x may not have been initialized error message? if so, can you show the part where your put Runnable x = new Runnable()?

Comment: I realized I put the Runnable code inside the onCreate. When I put the code outside the onCreate there was no local variable error. However the code did not run so no letters were set in the Buttons

Comment: put new Handler().post(x); on your onCreate.

Comment: It works much better now. Only problem is that once all my buttons have a set text it stops running. I am able to remove the text from the buttons and once I do so I want a remaining letter from my list to be set to that button.

Comment: then you can call new Handler().post(x); everytime you remove a text.

Comment: Thank you!!!! this works perfectly now!!! Would you be able to explain why I am able to call Handler().post(x) in onCreate() and after my removeLetters() function? Why would this not crash the application especially since both can be called at the same time?